# How to create nested directories using Nodejs in Windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to create a parent folder and a new folder inside that parent folder. Like this:
parent/child in the Documents folder in Windows 10/11 using Nodejs.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the sample which is the answer to your question.

```
private createTreeDirectory(){
    if(!fs.existsSync("\\Documents\\LumiPOS\\database\\lumi_pos.db")){
      fs.mkdirSync("\\Documents\\LumiPOS\\database", {recursive:true});
    }
  }
```